# Prove that $X(R)$ is not normal

Tags: general-topology

I was doing an exercise guide and the following is related to this

[Prove that it is first countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208680/prove-that-it-is-first-countable)

Let $H:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\;:\; y>0\}$ and $R=\{(x,y)\in  \mathbb{R}^2\;:\; y=0\}$. Notice that $\tau$ he topology of $H$ induced by $ \mathbb{R}^2$. Let the set  $X(S):=H\cup S$, where  $S\subset R$.

Define the topology $\tau^{\star}$ over the set  $X(S)$ as  the generated topology $\tau$ and the set $\mathcal B$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is formed by all the sets of form$\{x\}\cup B$, where $x\in S$ and $B\subset H$ is an open ball tangent to $R$ at the point $\{x\}$.

Prove that $X(R)$ is not normal

My attempt:

Let  $Q=\{(x,0)\in R\;:\; x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $I:=R\setminus Q$ (are closet of $X(R)$). Let $Q\subset V$, $I\subset U$ two open set of $X(R)$,

Let $I_n$ is the set of all  $x\in I$ such that there exists an open ball, $B\subset H$, of radius $1/n$, tangent to $x$ such that  $\{x\}\cup B\subset U$.

Let $I=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}$. (how can i test this?)

Now there is $n$ such that $(\overline{I_n})^{\circ}\cap Q\neq \emptyset$ ((because R is not the countable union of closed interior empty

but I know how to continue

Thanks

Comment: you are correct... and I recommend you just read what you wrote a bit more and you may figure it on your own.

Comment: i can't prove this $I=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}$

Comment: Take any $x\in I$. Since $x\in U$ and $U$ is open, there must exist $n$ and an open ball, $B\subseteq H$, of radius 1/n, tangent at $x$ and contained in $U$ (i.e. $B\subseteq U$). So $x\in I_n$ (for this $n$). In particular $x\in\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}$ hence $I\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}.$ (The other inclusion $I_n\subseteq I$ for each $n$ and hence $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}\subseteq I$ is obvious by construction of $I_n$ since the $x$'s come from $I$ to begin with, before we put some $x$ in some $I_n.$)

Comment: Ok thanks.  How can I better explain this $(\overline{I_n})^{\circ}\cap Q\neq \emptyset$ ?

Comment: There must be at least one $n$ such that $\overline{I_n}$ is nonempty (by the Baire category theorem, even if you didn't mention it by name). Then $(\overline{I_n})^{\circ}$ is non-empty (for this $n$) and since the rationals are dense (i.e. intersect every non-empty open set) we have in particular that $\overline{I_n})^{\circ}\cap Q\neq \emptyset$. It is kind of obvious. To me, it looks like you wrote the entire solution with enough detail, but if you are asking then perhaps you feel you didn't understand it, so you should verify it on your own, slowly, to convince yourself that it is true.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I'll try to finish it

Comment: now that you made me explain it, I feel that I don't understand it. If there was no $n$ such that $(\overline{I_n})^{\circ}$ is non-empty, then the contradiction that we obtain is that we could obtain the reals as the union of countably many closed sets with no interior, namely all the rational singletons (each of which is closed, no interior) together with all the $\overline{I_n}$, assuming $(\overline{I_n})^{\circ}$ were empty for each $n$.

Comment: We have that $V'\in \tau^{\star}$, de $q\in (\overline{I_n})^{\circ}\cap Q$, satisfy that $V'\cap U\neq \emptyset$ therefore $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$. So  $X(R)$ can't be normal

Comment: This space is called the Niemitzky plane or the Moore-Niemitzky plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb Q^2 \cap H$ is countable and dense in $X(R)$.

**If** $X(R)$ were metrisable, it would thus be second countable and so all subspaces would be second countable.

But $R$ as a subspace is discrete (every basic neighbourhood of $(x,0)$ intersects $R$ only in that point) and uncountable so **not** second countable.

This contradiction is sufficient.

In fact one can even show with Jones' lemma (look it up) that $X(R)$ is not even normal. Your approach to showing non-normality is not needed. Said lemma suffices.

Comment: Do you know of a way to characterize those $S\subset \Bbb R\times \{0\}$  such that in the Niemitzky plane, $S$ and $ ( \Bbb R\times \{0\})\setminus S$ are (or are not) functionally separated?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet apart from that they must be $G_\delta$ in the reals, probably? Not really. But there consistently are uncountable subsets $S’$ of $R$ so that $X(S’)$ is normal.